# Is there a generic way to prevent HTTP timing attacks for sensitive requests?

Tags: http, timing-attack

If I have sensitive HTTP routes that could be subject to timing attacks (trying to guess an ID, user, etc.), is there a way without modifying the application code that it could be wrapped with a network tweak, proxy, or some other program so timing attacks could be obviated?

Best I've been able to find, and it's not ideal, is just adding fixed delay with `netem`, but if fast and slow is (e.g.) 1 and 10 ms, would need to add a lot of delay to try to make them blur together (e.g. +100 ms, then hopefully 101 ms vs. 110 ms + random internet delay, but this isn't optimal), vs. just trying to make them all 15 ms or something.

Comment: Why fixed?  Then it would be slow is 110ms and fast is 101ms.  It should be random.  A straight normal distribution might lead to a camel double hump effect but would certainly blur the lines.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to imply I didn't want a fixed delay added (the +100 ms), but to make them all take a uniform amount of time (e.g. 15 ms), maybe with some randomness as well. [Randomness isn't a silver bullet though](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/can-i-prevent-timing-attacks-with-random-delays?rq=1) and a few of the backend apps are off-the-shelf, so modifying them would be a lot of effort.

Comment: Yea, I didn't write an answer because I don't know it.  But based on "lead to a camel double hump effect" I'm glad my brain intuitively saw that silver bullet answer coming.